# NullPointerException when using rowtime with table api

Tags: apache-flink

I have following simple code against Flink 1.12.0, when I run it, an exception throws.

```
package org.example.model

import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Person2(name:String, birthday: Timestamp)
```

And

```
package org.example.sql2

import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.Date

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.timestamps.BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{AnyWithOperations, FieldExpression}
import org.apache.flink.types.Row
import org.example.model.Person2

object Sql014_EventTimeTest2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    val ds: DataStream[Person2] = env.fromElements(Person2("Tom", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime)), Person2("Jack", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime)))
    ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[Person2](Time.seconds(10)) {
      override def extractTimestamp(t: Person2): Long = t.birthday.getTime
    })
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    val table = tenv.fromDataStream(ds, $"name", $"birthday", $"rt".rowtime())
    table.toAppendStream[Row].print()
    env.execute()
  }
}
```

When I run the application, following exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(MiniClusterJobClient.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:996)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:74)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:572)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:116)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:419)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:286)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:201)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:154)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SourceConversion$4.processElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(BroadcastingOutputCollector.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(BroadcastingOutputCollector.java:32)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollect(StreamSourceContexts.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:394)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FromElementsFunction.run(FromElementsFunction.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:215)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while you are calling `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on `ds`, you aren't doing anything with the result of this call. If you rework the code like this, it should work:

```scala
val streamWithTSandWM = ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[Person2](Time.seconds(10)) {
  override def extractTimestamp(t: Person2): Long = t.birthday.getTime
})
val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
val table = tenv.fromDataStream(streamWithTSandWM, $"name", $"birthday", $"rt".rowtime())
```

Calling `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on a stream doesn't modify that stream, but instead returns a new stream that has timestamps and watermarks.

Comment: Thanks @devid-anderson for the pointing out the problem, it works now.